# Aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause not available for my SQL queries

Tags: sql

currently having issue while running below SQL query as it mentioned Column 'Dim_Merchant.MERCHANT_ID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

```
SELECT M.MERCHANT_ID, E.NAME,U.LAST_NAME, O.CITY FROM

Dim_Merchant M JOIN Fact_Transaction T ON
M.MERCHANT_ID = T.MERCHANT_ID

--JOIN Dim_Bank_Info BI ON
--T.BANK_ID = BI.BANK_CODE

JOIN Dim_Enterprise_Info E ON
T.ENTERPRISE_ID = E.ENTERPRISE_ID

JOIN Dim_User_Info U ON
T.USER_ID = U.USER_ID

JOIN Dim_Outlet_Info O ON
T.OUTLET_ID = O.OUTLET_ID


GROUP BY ROLLUP(O.CITY)
```

Comment: if there is aggregation, the aggregated field or fields MUST be in the `SELECT` statement

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Sample data and desired results would help explain what you are trying to do.  Is there something about the error message that you don't understand?  It seems clear to me.

Answer (score 0):

1) Try this:

```
SELECT M.MERCHANT_ID, E.NAME,U.LAST_NAME, O.CITY FROM

Dim_Merchant M JOIN Fact_Transaction T ON
M.MERCHANT_ID = T.MERCHANT_ID

--JOIN Dim_Bank_Info BI ON
--T.BANK_ID = BI.BANK_CODE

JOIN Dim_Enterprise_Info E ON
T.ENTERPRISE_ID = E.ENTERPRISE_ID

JOIN Dim_User_Info U ON
T.USER_ID = U.USER_ID

JOIN Dim_Outlet_Info O ON
T.OUTLET_ID = O.OUTLET_ID
```

2) Try this:

```
SELECT M.MERCHANT_ID, E.NAME,U.LAST_NAME, O.CITY FROM

Dim_Merchant M JOIN Fact_Transaction T ON
M.MERCHANT_ID = T.MERCHANT_ID

--JOIN Dim_Bank_Info BI ON
--T.BANK_ID = BI.BANK_CODE

JOIN Dim_Enterprise_Info E ON
T.ENTERPRISE_ID = E.ENTERPRISE_ID

JOIN Dim_User_Info U ON
T.USER_ID = U.USER_ID

JOIN Dim_Outlet_Info O ON
T.OUTLET_ID = O.OUTLET_ID
GROUP BY O.CITY, U.Last_Name, E.Name, M.Merchant_ID
```